# Ipython widgets interactive static HTML

Tags: python, widget, jupyter, interactive, nbconvert

I used to (about a couple of years ago) generate static web pages from Jupyter Notebook having Ipython widgets using nbconvert. The resulting HTML used to have interactivity as expected. However, now I see that HTML files from nbconvert do NOT have interactivity. I have tried the illusionist library as well but still can't get interactive widget.
Is there any other library or tool that can generate static HTML files having interactive widgets without having any Python backend.
I do see similar questions have been posted but none to those clearly answer why nbconvert doest work nor is any viable solution presented.
Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Plotly is less general but can retain interactivity within the `.ipynb` files served from static sites such as GitHub via nbviewer. (Use of nbviewer is important as the GitHub rendering, which should be more considered as a preview, doesn't allow this, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72451192/8508004).) Also, soon static webpages in JupyterLite and related web assembly flavors can now (or very soon) use ipywidgets so you could have full interactive widgets without Python running on a remote server. I wonder ...

Comment: <continuing>  if your post may work better as a post at [the Jupyter Community Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/) as it borders on [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?